# Swipe Right and left on Ionic React Card

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

In Ionic React, How to create Slider whose right and left slide slides partially and show options.

[image: Right Swipt Image]

Comment: Could you create an example app on stackblitz or codesandbox to show what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can try slidesPerView and spaceBetween in ion-slides. For more detail and example :> https://devdactic.com/dynamic-ionic-4-slides/
This example build by angular but I think react settings pretty same.

Comment: I know nothing about angular, it's hard to understand angular code for me.

Comment: I build an example for you. You can try  @NikhilPrasad

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React from 'react';
import { IonSlides, IonSlide, IonContent } from '@ionic/react';

// Optional parameters to pass to the swiper instance.
// See http://idangero.us/swiper/api/ for valid options.
const slideOpts = {
  slidesPerView: 1.6,
  spaceBetween: 10
};

export const SlidesExample: React.FC = () => (
  <IonContent>
    <IonSlides pager={true} options={slideOpts}>
      <IonSlide>
        <h1>Slide 1</h1>
      </IonSlide>
      <IonSlide>
        <h1>Slide 2</h1>
      </IonSlide>
      <IonSlide>
        <h1>Slide 3</h1>
      </IonSlide>
    </IonSlides>
  </IonContent>
);
```